# Create SpriteBatch throw IllegalArgumentException

Tags: libgdx, glsl, shader, vertex-shader

I'm using 2 stages. One for controls bar (buttons), one for the game.
The error send from Google Galaxy Nexus - 4.2.2

Here is my code

```
public BaseScreen(MyGame game) {
    cam = new OrthographicCamera();
    cam.setToOrtho(true, game.getGameWidth(), game.getGameHeight());
    camera = new PerspectiveCamera();
    viewport = new FitViewport(gameWidth, gameHeight, camera);

    shapeRenderer = new ShapeRenderer();
    shapeRenderer.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);
    batcher = new SpriteBatch();
    batcher.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);
}
```

and log:

```
STACK_TRACE=java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error compiling shader: Vertex shader(s) failed to link, fragment shader(s) failed to link.
ERROR: error(#275) Symbol 'v_texCoords' is defined with 2 different types between two stages
ERROR: error(#275) Symbol 'v_texCoords' is defined with 2 different types between two stages
at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch.createDefaultShader(SpriteBatch.java:158)
at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch.<init>(SpriteBatch.java:121)
at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch.<init>(SpriteBatch.java:74)
at c.j.a.<init>(BaseScreen.java:118)
at c.j.e.<init>(GameScreen.java:11)
at c.a.a(GOGGame.java:270)
at c.j.b.render(CardLobbyLoadingScreen.java:130)
at com.badlogic.gdx.Game.render(Game.java:46)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGraphics.onDrawFrame(AndroidGraphics.java:422)
at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1516)
at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1240)
```

Comment: Is this a deployed app, and the trace is from some user? There seems to be some bug in the device, because the default shader in SpriteBatch most certainly does not define two different types for `v_texCoords`.

Comment: yes this app was deployed. The stack trace was sent from user device